# Unit testing service dependency in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

Learning how to front end test, but can't get promises to work. I have a PostService that has some methods which return a promise using $q.

Running my specs, I'm getting "GettingTypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'spyOn(PostService, 'show').and.returnValue')"

```
angular.module('postmunkApp')
.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, $http, socket, $stateParams, PostService) {

PostService
  .show($stateParams.postId)
  .then(function(post) {
    $scope.post = post;
  });

$scope.savePost = function() {
  PostService
    .update({id: $stateParams.postId, title: $scope.post.title, body: $scope.post.body})
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
}

$scope.deletePost = function(post) {
  PostService
    .destroy(post)
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
};

});
```

Specs

```
describe('Controller: PostCtrl', function() {
  var PostCtrl, $httpBackend, $q, $scope, deferred, PostServiceSpy,  PostService;

  beforeEach(module('postmunkApp'));
  beforeEach(module('socketMock'));


  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _PostService_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    PostService = _PostService_;
    deferred = _$q_.defer();
    spyOn(PostService, 'show').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    $controller('PostCtrl', {$scope: $scope, PostService: PostService});
  }));

  it('should resolve promise', function () {
    deferred.resolve([{ title: 'This is a title' }, {title: 'This is another title'}]);
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($scope.post).not.toBe(undefined);
  });    

});
```

Comment: Add a console.log(PostService) just before your spy, do you see the service output in your console with a show function defined?

Comment: console.log(PostService); logs my service as "{all: function () { ... }, show: function (postId) { ... }, create: function () { ... }, update: function (params) { ... }, destroy: function (post) { ... }}"

Comment: I'm using jasmine v2.3.1 and jasmine-core v2.3.4. With "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",